# How to remove a footer for smaller screen size

Tags: html, ios, css, wordpress

I am using a wordpress responsive theme, however I need the footer to not appear on any screen size smaller than an ipad.  When viewed on an iphone 5 size screen the footer is too bulky and on some pages covers the content.  In this instance it would be much neater to remove this for mobile phone size screens.  Is there a CSS command, or any alternate method, to remove the footer below a certain screen size?

Many thanks in advance, Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say :

```
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 480px){
    #footer { 
        display : none; 
        visibility : hidden; 
    }
}
```

Or shorter :

```
@media (max-width: 480px){
    #footer { 
        display : none; 
        visibility : hidden; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `min-width: 0px` really needed?

Comment: No you're right, but it is only to show him what a CSS media query can do.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to trawl through the theme CSS to find the specific terms to call out (as it needed more than just .footer), now it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

A CSS media query should work

```
@media only screen and (max-width: enter breakpoint) {
#footer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```